# How to concatenate features of different types in a single python array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a features array that contains values of different types:

```
>>> features = train_df.values
>>> [x for x in features]

[True,
 array([2, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]),
 False,
 False,
 17,
 1,
 10,
 array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
```

I would like to produce a single python array that contains a concatenation of the all of the above features, i.e.

```
np.array([True, 2, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0, False, False, 17, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])
```

My goal is to train sklearn [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) with the above feature vector. What is the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a simple list comprehension.

```
>>> x
[True, array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), False, False, 17, 1, 10, array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]

>>> [j for i in x for j in (i if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else (i, ))]
[True, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, False, 17, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

>>> np.array(_, dtype='O')
array([True, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, False, 17, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

If you don't add `dtype='O'`, your bools will be casted to integers. It's upto you whether you want that or not. Working with object arrays are usually frowned upon, since they provide no vectorisation/efficiency benifits.